# How to write a django filter query for multiple values selected from a dropdown list?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-filter, django-filters

I wrote a views function to search/filter my data in django based on certain parameters. In the fields categories and locations the user can select multiple options to make the search.

My views function is as follows:

```
def search(request):

    queryset_list = Influencer.objects.order_by('-followers').distinct().values('id',
                                                                'full_name','username','photo','email_id','location_city','categories__name','website')

    # Username
    if 'username' in request.GET:
        username = request.GET['username']
        if username:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(username__icontains=username)

    #Full Name
    if 'fullname' in request.GET:
        fullname = request.GET['fullname']
        if fullname:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(full_name__icontains=fullname)

    # Location
    if 'location' in request.GET:
        location = request.GET['location']
        for i in location:

            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(location_city__icontains=i)

    # Categories
    if 'categories' in request.GET:
        categories = request.GET['categories']
        if categories:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(categories__name__iexact=categories)
```

The search function should return the data of all the categories and location for which the search is made. For e.g. if search is made for location Delhi and Mumbai then it should return all the Influencers which have their location as Delhi or Mumbai, same is for categories also.

The search function works perfect for single values but doesn't work for multiple values. For e.g if Delhi is send in the location category, then it returns correct results but if Delhi, Mumbai is selected then it reads only the first value i.e Delhi and applies the filter accordingly.

How should I modify the search query so that it works correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest approach would be like this Using [Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/queries/)

```
 from django.db.models import Q
    q = request.GET.get('q')
    if q:
    queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(Q(username__icontains=q)|Q(full_name__icontains=q)|
    Q(location_city__icontains=q)|Q(categories__name__iexact=q))
    return render(....
    else:
        messages.info(request,'no results found for {}',format(q))
```

And in your template use`name=q` in the search form.

```
  <form  action="{% url 'your search action' %}">
     <input type="text" name="q">
     <input type='submit' value='Search'>
   </form>
```

**OR** you can combine your all_queries like this with your solution:

```
all_queries = username_queryset_list|fullname_queryset_list|location_queryset_list|
categories_queryset_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Have  you tried using django-filterset for this purpose?

```
class InfluencerFilter(filters.FilterSet):
username = filters.CharFilter(name='username', lookup_expr='iexact')
fullname = filters.CharFilter(name='fullname', lookup_expr='iexact')
location = filters.NumberFilter(name='location', lookup_expr='exact')
categories = filters.CharFilter(name='categories', lookup_expr='exact')


class Meta:
    model = Influencer
    fields = ['username','fullname','location','categories']
```

And then in your view you can call this filter using:

```
filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
filter_class = InfluencerFilter
```

This would save you from all the tiring and redundant if statements and would only work for the query parameters that are available and ignore the rest.

Comment: where do I have to create this class in the views.py file?

Comment: @AhmadJaved Best practice would be to create an Influencer_filter.py file and put all your Influencer filter classes there.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do a search on my accounts: Possible search criteria's are free text (search_value), select group from select box (sel_group), checkbox only active ones (chk_active)

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        search_value = request.POST.get('searchValue', None)
        sel_group = request.POST.get('selGroup', 'ALL')
        chk_active = request.POST.get('chkActive', 0)

        filters = Q()
        if chk_active == '1':
            filters = filters & Q(is_active=True)
        if sel_group != 'ALL':
            filters = filters & Q(involvements__group__pk=sel_group)

        search_value = None if (search_value == '' or len(search_value) < 3) else search_value
        if search_value is not None:
            filters = filters & Q(last_name__icontains=search_value) | Q(first_name__icontains=search_value) | Q(email__icontains=search_value)

        users = get_user_model().objects.filter(filters)

        context = self.get_context_data(object_list=users)
        return render(request, template_name=self.template_name, context=context)
```

Hope this helps ;)